# symfony 2 , pagination

Tags: symfony

I'm just started working with Symfony2 and I have some problems with Pagination.

I have this code in my `Account` class:

```php
public function indexAction($page)
{
    $session = $this->get('session');

    if ($session->get('valid')=='true') {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entities = $em->getRepository('ProjectCRMBundle:Account')->findAll();


        $user = new Account();
        $form = $this->container->get('form.factory')->create(new AccountType());
        $total = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ProjectCRMBundle:Account')->createQueryBuilder('p')->getQuery()->getResult();

        /* total of résultat */
        $total_users    = count($total);
        $users_per_page = 1;
        $last_page      = ceil($total_users / $users_per_page);
        $previous_page  = $page > 1 ? $page - 1 : 1; 
        $next_page      = $page < $last_page ? $page + 1 : $last_page;

        /* résultat  à afficher*/
        $entities          = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ProjectCRMBundle:Account')->createQueryBuilder('p')->setFirstResult(($page * $users_per_page) - $users_per_page)->setMaxResults(1)->getQuery()->getResult();

        return $this->render('ProjectCRMBundle:Account:index.html.twig', array(
            'entities'      => $entities,
            'last_page'     => $last_page,
            'previous_page' => $previous_page,
            'current_page'  => $page,
            'next_page'     => $next_page,
            'total_users'   => $total_users,
            'form'          => $form->createView(),
            'user'          => $user,
        ));

        return $this->render('ProjectCRMBundle:Account:index.html.twig');
    } else {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('user_login'));
    }
}

/**
 * Creates a new Account entity.
 *
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Account();
    $form = $this->createForm(new AccountType(), $entity);
    $form->bind($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('account_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

    return $this->render('ProjectCRMBundle:Account:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    )); 
}
```

without forgetting the path on `account.yml`

```yaml
account:
    pattern:  /{page}
    defaults: { _controller: "ProjectCRMBundle:Account:index" , page: 1 }
```

At first look, it seems to work, but after trying to add a new account, I got this message:

> LIMIT argument offset=-1 is not valid

Can anyone solve my problem?

Comment: I've reindented your code, ugily code is unmaintainable. Also, you have 2 return statements after eachother, the last one will never get called.

Comment: I can only assume that the page that is being sent through is 0 rather than the default of 1 so taking away the `$users_per_page` would equal -1. If you are just looking for pagination (rather than doing some learning) have you thought about looking at https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle ?

Comment: i've tryed to install bundles but no one worded, and i'm running out of time, that's why i'm developping all the project by myself. the last thing to do to finish my site is pagination and i' can't see how.
The code i've sent you is working with my user's class, i don't know why it's not working with the account's class, is it because other classes depends on account which is not the case for user ??

Comment: I put together a working pagination with the help from this:
[Doctrine Pagination](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html)
and this: [Pagination like google](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11274294/1055533)

Ended up being no more than 20 rows of code.  

You just have to write the DQL yourself.